# R: summing specific elements in a symmetrical matrix

Tags: matrix

If I have a correlation matrix, I know I can use upper.tri or lower.tri to sum all values, but is there a way to sum just specific parts of the matrix?

For example, a correlation matrix of 5 variables:

```
> Matrix
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    4    3    1    2
[2,]    4    0    3    2    1
[3,]    3    3    0    2    1
[4,]    1    2    2    0    1
[5,]    2    1    1    1    0
```

If the first 2 variables belong to one group, while 3-5 belong to another, is there a way to just ask for the sum of the inter-group values? e.g., 3+3+1+2+2+1 = 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long winded answer but hopefully generic one to help you!

```
matrix <- matrix (c(0,4,3,1,2,4,0,3,2,1,3,3,0,2,1,1,2,2,0,1,2,1,1,1,0), nrow=5, ncol=5)
group <- list(group1=c(1,2), group2=c(3,4,5))
sum_matrix <- matrix(data <- rep(NA), nrow = length(group), ncol= length(group))

for (i in 1:length(group))
{
  for(j in 1:length(group))
  {
    ifelse(i==j, sum_matrix[i,j]<- NA, sum_matrix[i,j] <- sum(matrix[group[[i]], group[[j]] ]) )
   
  }
}
sum_matrix


sum(matrix[group2, group1])
sum(matrix[group1, group2])
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I couldn't get the last lines to work for some reason, but the output of 'sum_matrix' gives the answer I'm after.

Comment: Just a quick further one - is there an easy way to sum all of one group's values? e.g., for group 1 it would be all those above or below the triangle, so 4+3+3+1+2+2+1 = 16.